# Setting boot sequence on windows

Tags: windows, netboot

I want to try something similar to what Mac has i.e control the startup from the OS. In Mac you can choose to have the next boot to be a network boot or a CD boot or a Firewire boot.
Similarly, is there a way in windows using WMI/wbem scripting we can set the next boot in network boot or CD mode instead of local hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard OS function for this but a Control Panel applet from the hardware vendor may provide this (this is the case on some toshiba laptops I've seen for example) but it is not universal. Apple have an advantage in that they control the OS and the hardware and they make use of EFI rather than a traditional BIOS so it is easier to communicate between the OS and the system firmware.

Answer (score 0):

well, do u want to set the next boot option from windows or from the BIOS when the PC starts ??

Comment: From Windows within the OS, not BIOS.

Comment: well, It depends on your hardware vendor that if they had provided any software to control the boot sequence from within the operating system.